# How to make Swipe gestures for SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swipe

Is there any simple way for gesture recognition in SwiftUI?

According to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iwx0w7T-lg4) I have copied the code according to my case:

(I need to change the value "page2" from the other view)

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwipeGesture: UIViewRepresentable {

    @Binding var page2: Int

    func makeCoordinator() -> SwipeGesture.Coordinator {
        return SwipeGesture.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SwipeGesture>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        let left = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.left))
        left.direction = .left

        let right = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.right))
        right.direction = .right

        view.addGestureRecognizer(left)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(right)
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SwipeGesture>) {

    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject{

        var parent : SwipeGesture

        init(parent1 : NSObject){
            parent = parent1
        }

        @objc func left(){
            print("left swipe")
            parent.page2 = parent.page2 + 1
        }

        @objc func right(){
            print("right swipe")
            parent.page2 = parent.page2 - 1
        }
    }
}
```

Used in ContentView by: `SwipeGesture(page2: $page2)`

```
@State var page = 0
```

is for the main View

```
@Binding var page: Int
```

is for this `SwipeGesture struct`
The problem is:[image]

Any ideas what I did wrong?

SwiftUI Code:

```
var body: some View {
// MARK: - Screen Layers
    ZStack {

        // Logo name
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: self.margin1)
            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "lobby_bg-logo")!)
                .renderingMode(.original)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(height: self.screenH * 0.3125)
            Spacer()
        }
        SwipeGesture(page2: $page2)
```

The error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'NSObject' to type 'SwipeGesture'
>   Occurs in `init` part.

Comment: I assume you need SwiftUI DragGesture, but it would be more clear if you provide SwiftUI code where you want to use it.

Comment: @Asperi Updated. Thx. But it won't help. Without parameters State and Binding it goes well before I "init" the values. It is exactly about NSObject

Comment: Check your type bro. `parent` must be `SwipeGesture`. Not `NSObject`. `Coordinator` class conforms `NSObject` to delegate `SwipeGesture` view. Check it out https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Comment: The problem with this is that the SwipeGesture blocks everything under it. So those views can't, for example, use `.tapGesture { ... }` I'm not sure what the solution is. Can this be fixed easily, or better to implement a swipe with `DragGesture`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fix

```
class Coordinator: NSObject{

    var parent : SwipeGesture

    init(parent1 : SwipeGesture){    // << corrected type !!
        parent = parent1
    }
```